# How to pass data from the line chart using Amcharts library

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, amcharts

sorry if my question is really from the beginning :(, i really have no idea how to manipulate my data from my model to put it on the line chart using amchart.

i already saw their documentation but still no idea about it.

here is my view

```
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
var data = [];
var value = 50;
for(let i = 0; i < 300; i++){
  let date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  date.setDate(i);
  value -= Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10);
  data.push({date:date, value: value});
}
chart.data = data;
// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.tooltipText = "{value}"

series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

//chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>
```

```
Here is my model and controller

  function get_data(){
      $this->db->select('year,purchase,sale,profit');
      $result = $this->db->get('account');
      return $result;
  }

    function index(){
      $this->load->model('Chart_model');
      $data['data'] = $this->Chart_model->get_data();
      $this->load->view('chart_view',$data);
    }
```

i just need a guide to how can i make it show to the line charts. the y axis should display the profit and the x axis should display the year and purchase. thanks for your help.

Comment: You must have created div with id 'chartdiv' in your html, right?

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link,its help you lot
[https://www.amcharts.com/demos/partitioned-bar-chart/]